# Button in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following button:

[image]

I need to do it using HTML/CSS3. I have tried a lot of things like radial gradient.

I have tried -webkit-gradient(linear.. and -webkit-gradient(radial...

Any help or ideas??

Comment: Can you give the code that you tried? Also, a background may be easier to do just with an image.

Comment: Why do you *need* to do it with CSS?

Comment: I need to do it with CSS because we are optimizing the code and it needs to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an attempt at it:](http://jsfiddle.net/sYuaU/)

```css
div {
    background-image:-moz-radial-gradient(50% 100%, yellow, #FFCC00, yellow);
    background-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(50% 100%, yellow, #FFCC00, yellow);
    background-image: radial-gradient(50% 100%, yellow, #FFCC00, yellow);
    height:47px;
    width:202px;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:47px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color:#AA8100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

radial gradients only work with circles or ellipses, so you won't be able to get that style without an image or some css canvas...

Answer (score -1):

With CSS, the closest I can get is just a linear gradient, top to bottom. The little bit of light at the bottom is pretty hard to do with CSS. You might need to consider that an image, if it's not large, will not affect performance too much.

You might want to watch your server side coding for performance, because that's the issue most of the time. IF it is because you need to load alot of images, you could get all the images on your site and put it in a single file, and always get that file but with different background positions. StackOverflow uses this too. This technique is called using `sprites`

A guide on what it does and how it works can be found here: [CSS Tricks: Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

This is the closest I got: http://jsfiddle.net/DU3QJ/